# how to disable closing a tab in tkinter pnotebook?

Tags: python, tkinter, tabs, disable

I am simply trying to disable the user from closing a tab in tk Pnotebook (not the window close button but the tab close button)

based on tkinter pNoteBook documentation, I can only change the state of the tab itself from normal  to disable to hide and that's completely not what I am asking for
Thank you

https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html#ttk.Notebook

https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tkinter.Notebook

[check the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Go5d.png)

Comment: [Edit] your Question and add a link to the *pNoteBook documentation*

Comment: Edited with documentations

Comment: You are linking to `ttk.Notebook`, i'm not aware that one can add a `x` to a `tab`. [Edit] your Question and show your code `import ????; nb = pnotebook(???`.